# Struggling to create a link to another cell in a different worksheet via VBA

Tags: excel, vba, syntax, hyperlink

```
Sub AddNewGuidance()

    Dim Last_Row As Long

    'Code below is to ensure I always have a new number to help with assigning unique names to cells containing guidance
    Static I As Long
    I = I + 1 + Now()

    Dim wsl As Worksheet
    Set wsl = Worksheets(1)

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Worksheets(2)

    Dim NewName As String 'This is simply the string to be paired with "I's" value to aid in creating uniquely named cells
    NewName = "Guidance" & "" & I 'Concatenation of string and value of I to acquire unique name

    ws.Activate 'Activating the sheet where the guidance on how to perform the checklist task will be located
    Last_Row = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(7, 0).Select

    With Selection                      'Selecting the 7th row below the last cell with text
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft   'There are 6 spaces added to add separation between text
        .VerticalAlignment = xlTop      'We format this cell now
        .WrapText = True
        .Font.Size = 10        
    End With

    ActiveCell.Rows("1:1").EntireRow.Select ' We now select the row that the selected cell  is in
    Selection.RowHeight = 150 'We now format the row that the selected cell is in
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1:A6").Select '6 rows below newly formatted cell are selected
    Selection.Style = "Accent3" 'These 6 rows are now given a gray color
    ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Range("A1").Select 'The newly formatted cell is selected again


    ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add NewName, RefersTo:=Selection 'Newly formatted/ selected cell now given a name
    wsl.Activate 'The worksheet actually containing checklist questions is selected

    Dim Rng As Range
    For Each Rng In Range("A16:A150")  'All questions are contained in this range
        If Rng.Value = "" Then Rng.Offset(0, 1).Select 'We want to loop through and find new blank cell
        'We then want to select the cell to the right of that blank cell
        Exit For 'We want to exit the loop once that is done

    Next Rng

    ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection, Address:="", SubAddress:= _
         "'General List Guidance'!Last_Row", TextToDisplay:="LINK"
End Sub
```

Finally, we want to take our newly selected blank cell on the checklist sheet and link it to our newly created/named guidance cell that we created earlier on the "ws" sheet I am unsure how to reference back to it since the guidance "names" will always be new and I seem unable to use my `Last_Row` variable as a range in order to link back to it

Note: "ws" is equal to the sheet named "General List Guidance". I used its full name in my attempt to refer back to it since I am unsure on how to incorporate the "dimmed" name of `ws` here. Right now, a link is created, but I get an invalid reference when I click on it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```vb
Sub AddNewGuidance()
    
    Static I As Long
    Dim wsl As Worksheet, ws As Worksheet, wb As Workbook
    Dim NewName As String, rng As Range, c As Range
    
    'Code below is to ensure I always have a new number to help
    '  with assigning unique names to cells containing guidance
    I = I + 1 + Now()
    NewName = "Guidance" & I
    
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook 'or ThisWorkbook if that's where this code is running
    Set wsl = wb.Worksheets(1)
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets(2)
    'Selecting the 7th row below the last cell with text
    Set rng = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(7, 0)
    With rng
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
        .VerticalAlignment = xlTop
        .WrapText = True
        .Font.Size = 10
        .EntireRow.RowHeight = 150
        .Offset(1, 0).Resize(6).Style = "Accent3" 'gray color
    End With
    wb.Names.Add NewName, RefersTo:=rng 'Newly formatted/ selected cell now given a name

    For Each c In wsl.Range("A16:A150").Cells
        If Len(c.Value) = 0 Then
            wsl.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=c.Offset(0, 1), Address:="", _
                        SubAddress:=NewName, TextToDisplay:="LINK"
            Exit For 'done searching
        End If
    Next c

End Sub
```

Note there's almost never a need to select ranges/sheets before working with them - that's just an artifact of the way the macro recorder creates code.

Comment: You sir are an Excel god. The code you suggested worked wonderfully. Also, thank you for the tip on not always having to select ranges. I will definitely need to keep that in mind. I aim to hopefully be VBA Yoda one day, but I have many courses to take before I can get close to claiming such a title. Again, you have my gratitude, and seeing this code work genuinely made me smile as it A)solved my problem, and B) taught me something new.

Comment: Good to hear it worked for you.  A bit more info on [not] using `Select` - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba